# Editing config file inside Docker image on client site

Tags: python, docker

I have created and pushed a docker image to Docker Hub. Am pulling the image on the other side on the client machines. However there are config files inside the image that are client site specific (change from site to site) - for example the addresses of the RTSP cameras per site. How would I edit these files on each client site? Do I need to manually vim each image on each client site manually or is there a simpler way?

Or is the solution to extract these config files entirely from the image, copy them separately to client site and somehow change the code to reach these files outside the image?

thanks

Comment: You mount the config file from the outside (the host) using the `-v` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better keep your image in DockerHub as a baseimage w/o any dynamic config in it (or simply ignore it).

On the client side, you need to create your local image from the baseimage from the DockerHub with replacing via COPY or by mounting it as Volume.

OR as @Klaus D. commented